# How to convert a string to google.protobuf.Timestamp?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a Go string `x := "2020-09-01T21:46:43Z"`

Here is my Protobuf3:

```
message MyMessage {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp mytimestamp = 1;
}
```

How can I convert this string `x` to a `google.protobuf.Timestamp`?

Comment: [The language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ptypes](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes) package which has helpers to convert to/from protobuf types.

Two functions to help you are:

---

[ptypes.Timestamp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#Timestamp): Converts a `Timestamp` to a `time.Time`:

```
func Timestamp(ts *timestamppb.Timestamp) (time.Time, error)
```

---

Call the timestamppb.New function. This converts a `time.Time` to a `Timestamp`:

```
func timestamppb.New(t time.Time) *timestamppb.Timestamp
```

---

Note that both deal with a [time.Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), the time type in the standard library. You will first need to parse your string into a `time.Time` using [time.Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse).

---

Putting it all together we have:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"
)

func main() {

    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-09-01T21:46:43Z")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    pb := timestamppb.New(t)

    fmt.Println(pb)
}
```